# How do I print Ansii c Extended Code in a program?

Tags: c

[image]

how do i make input or output of highlighted code?

I also use this code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
 int main()
  {
    int e;
    char ch;

    printf("\n Enter a character : ");
    scanf("%c",&ch);
    e=ch;
    e=e-6;
    ch=e;
    printf("\n This is  % c before the character W :",ch);
    getch();
    return 0;
  }
```

this code will print **Q** for input **W**

Input

```
Enter a character : W
```

Output

```
This is  Q before the character W
```

Answer (score 2):

The numbers in the `Alt-` column means that you have to read *two* characters: If the first is zero then you have to read another to get the key.

Comment: The fact is how do I use it in a program?

Comment: @Woliul What do you mean, what you use the alt-key combinations for? Whatever you like.

Comment: I want to use it in a c program. If I could, I want to use it as input, then the output will be the character.

Comment: @Woliul And I told you in the answer what you have to do: Read two characters (technically two bytes). The output (echoing) you probably have to do yourself, as well as translating the scan code in the second byte to a character.

Comment: I want to use input as W and the output will be Q